# find out the coordinate of the symbol for given x, y axis in a graph image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

Orignal image,

[image: Original image]

opencv with template matching was used to find all the "O" sympbol, and the center position of the symbols was also saved as a list already.

```py
    def match(template, img, threshold):
        pos = []
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        template= cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        w, h = template.shape[::-1]
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            pos.append([int(pt[0]+w/2),int(pt[1]+h/2)])
    return pos
```

After processing,

[image: After image]

Is there any way to fit the center position of the symbol to given x and y axis in this graph to get the coordinate?
the round symbol coordinate result is supposed to be presented such as,

`O_position = [[250,10], [500,5], [1k,10], [2k,5], [4k,15], [8k,15]]`

What I have tried is to defined the definite coordinate of the axis value manually first. As following,

```py
axis_position = {
    "f125": x1,    "f250": x2,    "f500": x3,    "f1k": x4,
    "f2k": x5,    "f4k": x6,    "f8k": x7,    
    "db-10": y1,    "db0": y2,    "db10": y3,    "db20": y4,    
    "db30": y5,    "db40": y6,    "db50": y7,    "db60": y8,
    "db70": y9,    "db80": y10,    "db90": y11,    "db100": y12,
    "db110": y13,    "db120": y14
}
```

Finding out the minnimum `abs(pos_x-xi)` and `abs(pos_y-yi)` to determine the position on the axis, respectively.

Comment: Isn't the centre point at `int( (pt[0] + w) /2 ), int( (pt[1] + h) / 2 )` ?

Comment: Thanks for explanation, @DrBwts, the center point position is exactly what you mentioned, but the problem to me is to determine the coordinate after find all the center point. The manner I was considering now was added after the original article.